# Can controller.StartImageStream() be restarted after controller.stopImageStream or is there a way to pause

Tags: flutter, camera

Hope someone can help me.  I am a blind guy and am creating a app to recognise ZA banknotes.  I find my results is better after controller.stopImageStream(); rather than running the image stream continuesly.  How can I restart controller.startImageStream() after the stop?  or is there a way to pause the imageStream rather then stopping it.  Thank you

```
    setState(() {});

    controller.startImageStream((CameraImage img) {
      controller.stopImageStream();
      if (!isDetecting) {
        isDetecting = true;

        int startTime = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

        Tflite.runModelOnFrame(
```